# Using natively installed Tensorflow with Anaconda Python (in Visual Studio)

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, numba

I am new to the field of machine learning and GPU computing. My development environment is Visual Studio 2017, and I'm using an NVidia GPU (with CUDA Compute Capability 6.1). I've installed both native Python 3.6 and Anaconda (which come with Visual Studio 2017 as selectable components during installation), and I've also successfully installed CUDA, cuDNN, TensorFlow, and Keras, which are all up-and-running.

However, the problem comes when I tried to write some CUDA codes with Numba in Python. It seems that only Anaconda (but not the native python interpreter) supports Numba. So I have to switch the interpreter of the Visual Studio solution to Anaconda 4.4. However, my Tensorflow distribution (and keras) are installed with the native pip3 approach (so, the project solution uses the native Python 3.6 interpreter), and once I switch the interpreter to Anaconda, it doesn't recognize "import tensorflow" anymore. But if I use Python 3.6 interpreter, it wouldn't recognize "from numba import cuda".

Therefore, I wonder if there's any way to point my Anaconda interpreter to the already-installed tensorflow distribution (instead of having to install another one within Anaconda environment)? Also, if I install two copies of TensorFlow (i.e. one with pip3 install in native python, another with "pip install" in Anaconda virtual environment), would that have any adverse effects on my previous TensorFlow projects with native python interpreter?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - simply install what you need you need where you need it.  The Anaconda python install and python.org one will have completely separate packages.  Also look into conda environments to manage isolated envs - https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html